# Fedex SOAP Track Api hit with parameters in java

Tags: java

Hiey

I am using Fedex tracking soap api to track my order with production tracking number with soap api.

i need to hit fedex tracking url with parameters but i m stuck in parameters because i have very few experience with SOAP api.

Here is the list of params:-

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v9="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v9"> <soapenv:Header/> 

    <soapenv:Body> <v9:TrackRequest> <v9:WebAuthenticationDetail> <v9:UserCredential> <v9:Key>XXXX</v9:Key> <v9:Password/> </v9:UserCredential> </v9:WebAuthenticationDetail> 

    <v9:ClientDetai l> <v9:AccountNumber>XXXX</v9:AccountNumber> <v9:MeterNumber>XXXX</v9:MeterNumber> <v9:Localization> <v9:LanguageCode>EN</v9:LanguageCode> <v9:LocaleCode>US</v9:LocaleCode> </v9 :Localization> </v9:ClientDetail> <v9:TransactionDetail> <v9:CustomerTransactionId>Track By Number_v9</v9:CustomerTransactionId> 

<v9:Localization> <v9:LanguageCode>EN</v9:LanguageCode> 

<v9:LocaleCode>US</v9:LocaleCode> </v9:Localization> </v9:TransactionDetail> 

<v9:Version> <v9:ServiceId>trck</v9:ServiceId> <v9:Major>9</v9:Major> 

<v9:Intermediate>1</v9:Intermediate> <v9:Minor>0</v9:Minor> </v9:Version> 

<v9:SelectionDetails> <v9:CarrierCode>FDXE</v9:CarrierCode> 

<v9:PackageIdentifier> <v9:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v9:Type> 

<v9:Value> XXXX </v9:Value> </v9:PackageIdentifier> 

<v9:ShipmentAccountNumber/> <v9:SecureSpodAccount/> <v9:Destination> 

<v9:StreetLines>Address_Line</v9:StreetLines> <v9:City>City</v9:City > 

<v9:StateOrProvinceCode>XX</v9:StateOrProvinceCode> 

<v9:PostalCode>XXXX</v9:PostalCode> 

<v9:CountryCode>XX</v9:CountryCode> </v9:Destination> </v9:SelectionDetails> </v9:TrackRequest > </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no time to help you right now, but I would like to recomend you to use [SOAP UI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/). 
This tool can help you to generate an request from WSDL.